# Storyboard design pattern (to share or not to share)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

This is probably largely preferential but I'd like to know if there are any reasons to decide one way or another on this.

When designing with storyboards you invariably end up with a number of view controllers.  I'm looking at the overhead of a strict MVC approach where each controller is implemented in its own UIViewController subclass with corresponding UIView subclass (and even view model class for MVVM), and that seems to get out of hand quickly – it takes no time to add dozens of files to the project (many with little function).  An alternative approach would be to link all the views to a common controller representative of all of the storyboard functionality.

My inclination is that if you don't have substantial controller code for any individual view controller, then the combination of all of them into one shouldn't be of harm to the readability of the code (and may enhance it over adding a large number of source files).  On the other hand, if you have significant functionality to implement for any particular view controller, then it should be encapsulated within it's own controller.

In most situations I'd build all controllers to be as reusable as possible (encapsulated in their own custom UIViewController subclasses). Storyboards put this in an interesting light though since they seem to be geared towards sequences of views that typically have few entry points.

Comment: IMHO each Storyboard view controller should have their own `UIViewController` subclass. Each `UIViewController` subclass should encapsulate specific functionality and this should not (in general) be shared across multiple view controllers. If you do have shared code then you can separate that out into it's own file / library / class. Don't let your `UIViewController` subclasses get too big and unwieldy; this makes them very difficult to maintain.

Comment: So I've ended up creating custom UIViewController subclasses but using a shared view model object to track all of the data being collecting across views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is correct

- If you don't have much functionality in each VC (ViewController) them combine all your code into one VC. The only drawback to this approach is that you won't be able to implement view specific code and every view where you will use this common VC will execute the same code whether its needed there or not. e.g. code in viewWillAppear etc.
- Similarly if you have a lot of functionality for a particular view then its better to put it under its own VC
- This is just a suggestion, if you need to use some common code logic between multiple VCs then instead of doing copy and paste in each VC of the same code, make it into a method of type Category and then call it where ever its needed. So change the code only at 1 place.

More VCs doesn't necessarily mean bad design. In my opinion its easier to maintain that way. My two cents. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Each scene in your storyboard should have its own UIViewController subclass. Even doing it like this it's way too easy to get huge unmaintainable view controllers (MVC = Massive View Controller). Putting all the code for multiple scenes in the same view controller would create even bigger ones and also violate the Single Responsibility Principle. Each class should do only a single thing.

That also means you shouldn't duplicate the common functionality into all your UIViewController subclasses. Then they again would do multiple things - the common stuff and their actual purpose. Instead you can put your common code in other controller objects (which are not descendants of UIViewController) and use them in your view controllers.

Depending on the usecase a common base class would work as well, but it's always preferable to use composition instead of inheritance.

Another nice thing about other controller objects is that you also can add them directly in Interface Builder and connect actions and outlets to them. Your main view controller class often doesn't even have to know they exist.

Comment: I agree.  I'm looking at a case where each controller is pretty puny – basically a series of form screens collecting info – so it just seems a bit excessive.  It almost always ends up that you go back and create custom subclasses for maintenance purposes though anyways...